# Finding the singular points and residues of a function --- help

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, laurent-series

can anyone help?

$\ f(z)=\frac{\sin(z)+1}{\sin^2(z)}$

Find the singular points of this function, classify them, and compute residues in these points. Try to demonstrate different methods for the computation of residues.

What are the singular points of this function and what methods should I use to find the residues? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have $\ f(z)=\frac{\sin z+1}{\sin^2z}$.

Each zero $z_0$ of $\sin$ is an isolated singularity of $f$. Since $z_0$ is a zero of order $2$ of $\sin^2$ and not a zero of $ \sin z+1$, f has a pole of order $2$ at $z_0$.

We have, with $g(z):=(z-z_0)^2f(z)$:

$Res(f; z_0)= \lim_{z \to z_0}g'(z)$.

Your turn: what are the zeros of $\sin$ ?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The roots of the denominator are all  poles of order 2 Hence you have poles of order 2 for $-\pi ,0, \pi , 2\pi ,...$ . As for the residues , use the following formula: $$\operatorname{Res}(f,z_k) =(\lim_{z\to z_k}(z-z_k)^2f(z))^{'}$$. Another way to calculate the residue in the specific excercise is to find the Laurent expansion of these functions.

Comment: Your formular $\operatorname{Res}(f,z_k) =\lim_{z\to z_k}(z-z_k)^2f(z)$ is not correct ! It should read $\operatorname{Res}(f,z_k) =\lim_{z\to z_k}[(z-z_k)^2f(z)]'$. Example: $f(z)=1/z^2$. We have: $Res(f,0)=0$. Your formular gives $Res(f,0)=1$,

Comment: Yes you are right i forgot the symbol forall this quantity thanks

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments. so when you sub the points into that formula what do you get?

Comment: A good way to solve this is by using the identity $\sin^2(z)=1/2_1/2 \cos(2z) $ and then use the power series representation of the denominator , common factor is $z^2$ and then you use the formula above to calculate the residues. $z^2$ gets simplified and you just find the derivative and put zero inside.

Answer (score 0):

$$\newcommand{\Res}{\operatorname*{Res}}
\begin{align}
\Res_{z=k\pi}\left(\frac{\sin(z)+1}{\sin^2(z)}\right)
&=\Res_{z=k\pi}\left(\frac1{\sin(z)}\right)+\Res_{z=k\pi}\left(\frac1{\sin^2(z)}\right)\\
&=\Res_{z=0}\left(\frac1{\sin(z+k\pi)}\right)+\Res_{z=0}\left(\frac1{\sin^2(z+k\pi)}\right)\\
&=(-1)^k\Res_{z=0}\left(\frac1{\sin(z)}\right)+\Res_{z=0}\left(\frac1{\sin^2(z)}\right)\\[3pt]
&=(-1)^k\cdot1+0\\[12pt]
&=(-1)^k
\end{align}
$$
Since $\lim\limits_{z\to0}\frac{z}{\sin(z)}=1$ and $\frac1{\sin^2(z)}$ is an even function.